Weak Stationarity for Neural Network Input?
I am taking a course that detailed that input data into neural networks should be at least weakly predictive and weakly stationary (stable mean).
Does this principle apply to other ML models like tree-based algorithms or clustering?
Moreover, in general, is stationarity of features always required to construct meaningful time-series analysis?

Yes, it is essential to ensure that your time-series exhibit atleast some form of stationarity for predictive time-series based ML models.
When estimating a Neural Network (NN) or other machine learning models on non-stationary time-series data, the model may primarily capture the auto-correlation present in the data. Consequently, for a one-step ahead prediction of $X_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t$, the model degenerates to using only $X_t$ as the predictor. This is undesirable, as the model fails to utilize the richness of the input data to generate meaningful predictions. A brief LinkedIn Article explains this issue.
It is important to note that you can use trend- and/or seasonal-stationary input-data for your NN models. Depending on the complexity of the model, the NN model will try to capture the trend + seasonality of the time-series and use these as separate predictors. However, research by G.P Zhang et al. (2005) do suggest that de-trending and/or de-seasonalization can significantly reduce forecasting errors for your model, as opposed to using unprocessed raw data.
Regarding clustering, there is no requirement for a time-series to be stationary, as clustering models can group data points based on their similarities or distances in the feature space at a given time $t$. Even with temporal clustering, while stationarity is not a strict requirement, it can aid in data pre-processing and, in some cases, enhance clustering accuracy.

Perfect, this clears up a lot. Thank you so much!

What about using a residual connection in order to force the network to predict the change from t -> t-1
